# Error when deploy SSRS Report in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

We are having a problem when deploying SSRS report from AOT and AX Management Shell in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012.
When deploying the SSRS report from AOT, the infolog say:

> *The following components have not been installed or are not configured correctly:
>
>   Reporting extensions
>
>   Consult your administrator or the documentation.*

While when we try to deploy the report from the management shell, it say:

[management shell screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIEnv.png)

Also, we already run the AX as administrator and already validate settings for the report server from report server configuration.

Can anyone help us with this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried installing the reporting extensions? Does the user running the management shell have to necessary privileges on the SSRS database to deploy the reports?

Comment: the reporting extension is already installed,
and when we run the management shell as administrator its still not solve the problem

Comment: Could you [edit] this information into your question? This way, others can more easily find it. Could you also check the privileges of the user running the management shell on the SSRS database? This is not the same as running the management shell with administrator rights.

Comment: I have running the management shell as administrator, and still the error comes. The picture have been added in my question.
do you have any other solution @FH-Inway ?

Comment: Asked 3 years, 4 months ago. Viewed 654 times and still no answer.